# Switch API end points in a mobile app at run time

Tags: android, ios, api, development-environment, endpoint

We are building an app for iOS and Android platform which depends on a web application communicating via REST API calls.  The web application has its own user interface to define the entities and are hosted in three environments for easy management. test.mydomain.com for dev and qa team testing; uat.mydomain.com for the project stakeholders to verify and mydomain.com for the public end users.

Any changes made goes through test->uat->live cycle after necessary verification and validations.

The mobile app also comes in three flavours - test; uat; live. The test build points to test.mydomain.com as API endpoint and are loaded on the tablets and phones by developers and testers through USB deployment.  For uat either testflight or its Android equivalent is used and for the live, app stores are used.

When at time a bug report comes from public we want to reproduce it with a test data which developers have liberty to have in test.mydomain.com.  However the app downloaded from app store would be pointing to live server mydomain.com as its API end point. Sure we could take the exact source commit for the app version, build and test, but I would like to have the API end point to be changed **dynamically** in the app so that I could test many scenarios.

By the word dynamically I mean that I want to change the API end point in run time like via a settings menu.  The downside is that this menu should not be accessible for common end user and I though to password protect it. Then the password becomes universal and to circumvent that I have to come up with some other logic.

Is there any better idea on how I could switch the API endpoint dynamically/at run time, but at the same time not allowing the end users to use this feature?  I thought of the Android's solution to expose "Developer Settings" when the build number is tapped 7 times. But though to check here before doing so.

Comment: Is what you are saying has been developed already and facing this issue or your asking in prior to how to make structure for this type of scenario

Comment: Thanks for asking clarification, the development has just started and so far it has not even matured to do internal testing. So, "asking in prior to how to make structure for this type of scenario" applies.

Answer (score 0):

We can Switch API end point dynamically by creating multiple scheme and specify the endpoint of application in each scheme so that on every time to change the application endpoint from choose the scheme instead of manually change of endpoint each and ever time

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior using okhttp3.Interceptor on the android side. Change base urls by intercepting api calls.

1- Just create an interceptor and a base url holder which will contain base url.

```
class BaseUrlInterceptor (var baseUrlHolder: BaseUrlHolder) : Interceptor {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        val builder = request.newBuilder()
        baseUrlHolder.baseUrl?.let {
            adjustBaseUrl(request.url)?.let {
                request = builder.url(it).build()
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private fun adjustBaseUrl(url: HttpUrl): HttpUrl? {
        return baseUrlHolder.baseUrl?.let {
            url.newBuilder().host(it.toHttpUrl().host).build()
        }
    }
}
data class BaseUrlHolder(
    var baseUrl : String?= null
)
```

2- If you are using any dependency injection library, create a singleton BaseUrlHolder to adjust base url. If you are not using any then you can keep it static or you can implement manual dependency injection. You need to reach this BaseUrlHolder from anywhere that you want to change your base url.

3- Then add interceptor to your OkHttpClient.Builder.

```
...
val yourHttpClientBuilder= OkHttpClient.Builder()
yourHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(
                BaseUrlInterceptor({$yourSingletonBaseUrlHolder})
            )
...
```

4- At this point when you change {$yourSingletonBaseUrlHolder}.baseUrl you will change base url of your api calls for that http client.

```
{$yourSingletonBaseUrlHolder}.baseUrl = {myNewBaseUrl}
```

5- If you have multiple http clients and multiple base urls, just create multiple BaseUrlHolder and multiple interceptors for each and intercept with their interceptors and BaseUrlHolder.